# 64-bit variable acting strangely in c++

Tags: c++, bit

Why is the 64-bit variable acting so strage when the true bit is getting in the 31th position and futher?at the 32th bit it's returning a really big value and then it resets.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int a[65];
int main()
{
a[0]=1;
for(int i=0;i<=63;++i)
{
    for(int k=7;k>=0;--k)
    {
     for(int j=7;j>=0;--j)
    cout<<a[k*8+j];
    cout<<' ';
    }
    cout<<'=';
    cout<<(unsigned long long)(1<<i);
    cout<<'\n';
        a[i]=0;
        a[i+1]=1;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: if it resets after the 32nd bit you probably have a 32 bit value

Comment: Can you include a small, complete code example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: it hit the post button before entering the code by mistake...i'm new at stack overflow sorry

Comment: Try `1ull << i` to get an `unsigned long long` (C++11 required).

Comment: i know the array is 32-bit,but is used to simulate the bit representation,the value should be (unsigned long long)(1<<i);

Comment: @NicoSchertler well that worked...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(unsigned long long)(1<<i);
```

`1` is still an `int` here.You cast the result of `(1<<i)` into `unsigned long long`.

Use

```
cout<<((unsigned long long)1<<i);
```

or simply

```
cout<<(1ULL<<i);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are converting the result of `(1<<i)` you should make it:

```
((unsigned long long)1<<i);
```

or even simpler:

```
(ull1<<i);
```

where `ull` makes the literal `1` type unsigned long long.

Also I would suggest a different ,yet simpler, code if you do not have constraints or specific requirement:

```
#include <bitset>
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned long long a = 1;

    for(int i=0;i<=63;++i)
    {
        std::cout << std::bitset<64> (a) << " = " << a << "\n";
        a = a << 1;
    }
}
```